# SQL to XML and save it as XML file on machine

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xml-parsing, oracle11g

I have a query which is giving result in XML. Now i want to save this result as XML file so that i am able to use it for other purposes.

```
SELECT XMLElement("DEPARTMENT"
                 , XMLForest(department_id as "ID"
                            , department_name as "NAME"
                            )
                 )
  FROM departments
 WHERE department_id IN (10, 20);
```

How am i going to do it in oracle (PL/SQL).
I just read about UTL_FILE, but honestly an example to go about would really assist me both on Linux and Windows.

Comment: What code is being used to call that `SELECT` statement? Do you have a PHP script, a Java class, an entity object using Oracle ADF (in JDeveloper)? Are you using a SQL editor like Toad or PL/SQL Developer? Please provide more details about how you cannot export as XML.

Comment: @DaveJarvis PL/SQL procedure.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_file.htm#i997640 - Comes with examples of `PUTF`, `PUT_LINE`, etc.

Comment: Here's an example of what you are looking for: http://www.liberidu.com/blog/2008/02/14/howto-saving-xml-data-directly-to-disk/

Answer (score 0):

See link in comments. You can also try SYS_XMLGEN:

```
SELECT SYS_XMLGEN(XMLElement("DEPARTMENT"
             , XMLForest(deptno as "ID"
                        , dname as "NAME"
                        )
             )
             ) xml_output
  FROM scott.dept
 WHERE deptno IN (10, 20)
/
```